# can't pass the form-data correctly and make a post request

Tags: swift, post, request, form-data

i need to make "POST" request with formdata. when i do it in postman i get a positive result. but when I try to make a query in the code - I get an error that one of the parameters is not valid (but when I make a postman query with this parameter - everything is correct.)

in order to convert a dictionary into form-data, I use this method:

```
func getPostString(params:[String:Any]) -> String
       {
           var data = [String]()
           for(key, value) in params
           {
               data.append(key + "=\(value)")
           }
           return data.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "&")
       }
```

next I make a request:

```
 func request() {
        
        let dict: [String:Any] = ["xxx" : "xxx" , "xxx" : "xxx", ...]
    
        do {
            let postString = self.getPostString(params: dict)
            print(postString)
            
            guard let mainUrl = URL(string: "https://xxx.xxx.com/post/") else {
                return
            }
            var request  = URLRequest(url: mainUrl)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, Error) in
                
                if response != nil {
                    print(response)
                }
                
                if let Error = Error {
                    debugPrint(Error.localizedDescription)
                
                    return
                }
                if let data = data {
                    print(data)
                    
                    let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                    print(str)
                    
                    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                    do {
                        let response = try? jsonDecoder.decode(MyResponse.self, from: data)
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }
    }
```

when I see print(postString) - it comes out like this:

```
hash=fd399b06f23440bc0ff6f040800941f0&term_url_3ds=https://xxx-xxx.xx.xx/xx/xxxx/xxx&order_id=e9930dea-0340-4fe8-394b-a35fa3f915c2&payment_token={"xxx"}&order_currency=USD&order_amount=1.00&action=APPLEPAY&order_description=PAYMENT&payer_ip=192.168.1.101&client_key=8UYSDVUVS8J&payer_email=XXX@gmail.com&payer_phone=+14058370914
```

as I said above, in the response it occurs to me that the hash is not valid, but when I make the same request in postman, with the same hash - I get a different response.
i think i'm passing the form-data wrong somehow.

Comment: You can ask POSTMAN to generate Swift code to see what could be wrong. It's not beautiful code, but at least you could see the difference. I guess you might need to percent escape some values in the form data. Also, don't you need to set for `request` that the `Content-Type` is url encoded form data? Also, what's the hash? How is it calculated?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit speculative but doing it in comments would be tedious.

The first thing is that you do not appear to be setting a content type in the request. You need to add a content type header with the MIME type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

e.g.

```
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

You may also need to specify the character set if you have non ASCII characters in your request.

The other problem is that the values in your body string are expected to be URL encoded just like the the parameter string in a `GET` request.

You need to encode each value. In particular, using URLs as parameters without encoding can cause confusion (what if the URL itself has query parameters separated by `&`?). Also, the `+` in your phone number may get decoded by the server as a space.

Here's a way to construct the body that's safe, I think.

```
func getPostString(params: [String : any CustomStringConvertible]) -> String
{
    let queryParams: [String] = params.map {
        let (key, value) = $0
        let encodedValue = value.description.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)!
        return "\(key)=\(encodedValue)"
    }
    return queryParams.joined(separator: "&")
}
```

Here's an example of its use

```
let myParams: [String : any CustomStringConvertible] = [
    "payer_phone" : "+14058370914",
    "url" : "https://foo/bar?a=b&c=d",
    "number" : -9
]

print(getPostString(params: myParams)) 
// Prints payer_phone=%2B14058370914&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffoo%2Fbar%3Fa%3Db%26c%3Dd&number=%2D9
```

If you think `.alphaNumerics` is a bit aggressive you can add add other characters legal in a query parameter by constructing a custom `CharacterSet`. If you want non ASCII characters to be encoded, you'll definitely need to add a `charset` to the content type.